# Is there a way to match the columns of a dataset with another dataset rows in R

Tags: r, list, merge, tidyverse, lapply

I have these two datasets:

```
weather_data<- structure(list(`0` = c(20150310L, 20150310L, 20150310L, 20150310L, 
20150310L, 20150310L, 20150310L, 20150310L, 20150310L, 20150310L, 
20150310L), `0` = c(200L, 205L, 210L, 215L, 220L, 225L, 230L, 
235L, 240L, 245L, 250L), `1` = c(2.96667242050171, 4.08907222747803, 
3.34765760600567, 2.70875519514084, 4.04301458597183, 3.277907371521, 
1.19018948078156, 8.01013946533203, 3.17771905660629, 4.08452725410461, 
6.84288668632507), `2` = c(3.66441679000854, 3.8880712389946, 
5.4497694671154, 1.65072797238827, 1.22804968059063, 2.80022418498993, 
2.09879478812218, 7.83757948875427, 3.06818120181561, 3.02766072750092, 
2.10350251197815), `3` = c(0, 3.77445685863495, 0.66255909204483, 
0.979387938976288, 1.84569960832596, 1.28901898860931, 1.75025188922882, 
3.86244678497314, 2.02710714936256, 1.35766339302063, 5.03071141242981
), `4` = c(0, 0, 0, 1.86805146932602, 0, 2.28361964225769, 1.64410877227783, 
4.72498226165771, 0.665152907371521, 3.52564084529877, 5.99745666980743
), `5` = c(0, 0, 0, 1.86805146932602, 0, 2.28361964225769, 1.64410877227783, 
4.72498226165771, 0.665152907371521, 3.52564084529877, 5.99745666980743
), `6` = c(0, 0, 0, 0.255719035863876, 1.27965438365936, 2.14472162723541, 
1.15851271152496, 4.7572363615036, 2.20618277788162, 0.508674263954163, 
6.12584185600281), `7` = c(0, 0, 0.858640074729919, 1.97637134790421, 
1.29098010063171, 3.4027111530304, 0.723613187670708, 3.21064579486847, 
2.03270196914673, 2.11455392837524, 1.08344982564449), `8` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2.42211884260178, 0, 0, 0, 4.46288549900055, 0)), row.names = 85:95, class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
sensors<- structure(list(Agency.Station.ID = c("MI064E000.7U", "MI064E002.0U", 
"MI064E003.2U", "MI064E004.6U", "MI064E004.6V", "MI064E005.6U", 
"MI064E007.1U", "MI064E008.5U"), ColumnNum = 1:8), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to make a new dataframe that is created by matching the number in ColumnNum in sensors with the corresponding column in weather data with preserving the date and time which are columns (0,0) in weather data.
I tried the following code

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(sensors$ColumnNum, sensors$Agency.Station.ID),
               function(i)cbind(weather_data[1:2], weather_data[i]))

#adding new columns for each dataframe
colnames <- c("Date2","Time2","Precipitation") 
lst1<- lapply(lst1, setNames, colnames)
#adding the sensors name for each data frame 
lst1 <- Map(cbind, lst1, Agency.Station.ID = names(lst1))
#making a data frame for all the sensors
k <- do.call("rbind", lst1)
remove(lst1, sensors, colnames, weather_data)
```

and that should result in something like this:

```
    k <- structure(list(Date2 = c(20150309L, 20150309L, 20150309L, 20150309L, 
20150309L, 20150309L, 20150309L, 20150309L, 20150309L, 20150309L
), Time2 = c(1900L, 1905L, 1910L, 1915L, 1920L, 1925L, 1930L, 
1935L, 1940L, 1945L), Precipitation = c(20150309, 20150309, 20150309, 
20150309, 20150309, 20150309, 20150309, 20150309, 20150309, 20150309
), Agency.Station.ID = c("MI064E000.7U", "MI064E000.7U", "MI064E000.7U", 
"MI064E000.7U", "MI064E000.7U", "MI064E000.7U", "MI064E000.7U", 
"MI064E000.7U", "MI064E000.7U", "MI064E000.7U")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The Agency.Station.ID does not mater in this output example because it is not from my above data but I am unable to get the precipitation accurately. It is getting the Date instead. Could anyone help with all gratitude and appreciation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be easiest if you just rename the columns of the weather data first. (By the way, you shouldn't have multiple columns with the same name.) Then you can just switch from a wide to long dataframe.

```r
weather_data<- structure(list(`0` = c(20150310L, 20150310L, 20150310L, 20150310L, 
                                      20150310L, 20150310L, 20150310L, 20150310L, 20150310L, 20150310L, 
                                      20150310L), `0` = c(200L, 205L, 210L, 215L, 220L, 225L, 230L, 
                                                          235L, 240L, 245L, 250L), `1` = c(2.96667242050171, 4.08907222747803, 
                                                                                           3.34765760600567, 2.70875519514084, 4.04301458597183, 3.277907371521, 
                                                                                           1.19018948078156, 8.01013946533203, 3.17771905660629, 4.08452725410461, 
                                                                                           6.84288668632507), `2` = c(3.66441679000854, 3.8880712389946, 
                                                                                                                      5.4497694671154, 1.65072797238827, 1.22804968059063, 2.80022418498993, 
                                                                                                                      2.09879478812218, 7.83757948875427, 3.06818120181561, 3.02766072750092, 
                                                                                                                      2.10350251197815), `3` = c(0, 3.77445685863495, 0.66255909204483, 
                                                                                                                                                 0.979387938976288, 1.84569960832596, 1.28901898860931, 1.75025188922882, 
                                                                                                                                                 3.86244678497314, 2.02710714936256, 1.35766339302063, 5.03071141242981
                                                                                                                      ), `4` = c(0, 0, 0, 1.86805146932602, 0, 2.28361964225769, 1.64410877227783, 
                                                                                                                                 4.72498226165771, 0.665152907371521, 3.52564084529877, 5.99745666980743
                                                                                                                      ), `5` = c(0, 0, 0, 1.86805146932602, 0, 2.28361964225769, 1.64410877227783, 
                                                                                                                                 4.72498226165771, 0.665152907371521, 3.52564084529877, 5.99745666980743
                                                                                                                      ), `6` = c(0, 0, 0, 0.255719035863876, 1.27965438365936, 2.14472162723541, 
                                                                                                                                 1.15851271152496, 4.7572363615036, 2.20618277788162, 0.508674263954163, 
                                                                                                                                 6.12584185600281), `7` = c(0, 0, 0.858640074729919, 1.97637134790421, 
                                                                                                                                                            1.29098010063171, 3.4027111530304, 0.723613187670708, 3.21064579486847, 
                                                                                                                                                            2.03270196914673, 2.11455392837524, 1.08344982564449), `8` = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0, 0, 0, 0, 2.42211884260178, 0, 0, 0, 4.46288549900055, 0)), row.names = 85:95, class = "data.frame")
sensors<- structure(list(Agency.Station.ID = c("MI064E000.7U", "MI064E002.0U", 
                                               "MI064E003.2U", "MI064E004.6U", "MI064E004.6V", "MI064E005.6U", 
                                               "MI064E007.1U", "MI064E008.5U"), ColumnNum = 1:8), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                8L), class = "data.frame")

names(weather_data)[1:2] <- c("Date2","Time2")
# make sure the names match up with the correct columns
names(weather_data)[-(1:2)] <- sensors[sensors$ColumnNum[order(names(weather_data)[-(1:2)])], "Agency.Station.ID"]

tidyr::pivot_longer(weather_data, -c(1,2), names_to = "Agency.Station.ID", values_to = "Precipitation")
#> # A tibble: 88 × 4
#>       Date2 Time2 Agency.Station.ID Precipitation
#>       <int> <int> <chr>                     <dbl>
#>  1 20150310   200 MI064E000.7U               2.97
#>  2 20150310   200 MI064E002.0U               3.66
#>  3 20150310   200 MI064E003.2U               0   
#>  4 20150310   200 MI064E004.6U               0   
#>  5 20150310   200 MI064E004.6V               0   
#>  6 20150310   200 MI064E005.6U               0   
#>  7 20150310   200 MI064E007.1U               0   
#>  8 20150310   200 MI064E008.5U               0   
#>  9 20150310   205 MI064E000.7U               4.09
#> 10 20150310   205 MI064E002.0U               3.89
#> # … with 78 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the code. It is working well but the problem is it messes the column names when it bring the Agency.Station.ID. When I applies it to my data which has 487 Agency.Station.ID, it does not keep the same order for some reason that I could not figure out. Could you please help with that?

Comment: I resolved that by using the code below:                                                                
sensors<- sensors %>% arrange((ColumnNum))
vec<- sensors$Agency.Station.ID
names(weather_data)[-(1:2)] <- vec